# Could unusually high upload rates cause dropped connections during online gaming?

Tags: networking, upload, internet-speed

So I play Counter-Strike Global Offensive online from time to time, and recently I've noticed that my ping is about 30ms (pretty decent), but every other minute the connection drops for 5-10 seconds, which is very annoying. I ran the Windows network speed test, and the upload speed was about the same as the download speed, sometimes even higher, which I thought the provided had to restrict. And I wonder if those random connection glitches could have something to do with the high upload speed.

Comment: Type of connection? Fiber? Coaxial? ADSL/VDSL? Download and upload speeds in the various cases? Type of connection from your PC to your router/modem: Wifi (are you in a condo/apartment building?), Ethernet, Powerline adapater, other?

Answer (score 0):

Unusually high upload rates could cause drops depending on the game, but this would seem unlikely.

If you are getting drops every 2 minutes, something is wrong, and you should look at your mode and IDP. (Maybe an issue with PPP keepalives? Just a wild guess).

You haven't specified the type of connection, or if you live rurally, but it could also be an issue with dsl and electric fence or other periodic interference.

If you have large enough downloads, packet loss will typically slow the connection down, which could explain your speed limits. You can test this theory by watching speed patterns, and trying multiple simultaneous downloads.

Comment: It's weird that it used to work just fine three months ago... I don't know what has changed really... I might have to contact my ISP.